# message.content to json file python discord bot

Tags: python, json, bots, message, discord

I have a json file that stores power to people, I'm trying to make a command to give the power directly without needing to edit the json file:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('addpower'):
    text_in = message.content
    text_out = text_in[text_in.find("(") + 1:text_in.find(")")]

    for user in message.mentions:]
        try:
            user_add_power(user.id, int(text_out))
            await Bot.send_message(message.channel, "add {} power to {}".format(text_out, user.name))
        except: None
```

the `user_add_power` it's a part of another command that give power to everyone that type in my server.

According to my command, to give power to people, I need to type `"addpower @username (100)"` to give 100 power to the `@username` person.

I'm having trouble with this: `text_out = text_in[text_in.find("(") + 1:text_in.find(")")]`.
I would like to remove the `()` and just need to type `"addpower @username 100"` to give 100 power to the `@username` person.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the last word of `text_in` this way:

```
text_out = text_in.split()[-1]
```

split() cuts a string into words:

```
>>> text_in = "addpower @username 100"
>>> text_in.split()
['addpower', '@username', '100']
>>> text_in.split()[-1]
'100'
```